# Can I electronically substract an audio signal from an other one?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, signal

I encountered a little tricky situation in one of my project. I have two audio signals, A and A+B on two different wires. I would like to know if there is a solution to electronically retrieve the B signal alone. Is there any IC or any kind of circuit that could allow me to do that kind of substract ?

Best regards,

Vincent

Comment: Connect them to the two inputs of differential amplifier...You should get amplified version of B

Comment: I dislike "can I" questions because I have **no clue** what your level of skills is regarding electronics. There are many ways to add and subtract signals. Often an opamp is used.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=differential+amplifier.&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: This is more-or-less how FM stereo radio works. (L+R) and (L-R) transmitted 'separately', and then added to or subtracted from each other in a stereo receiver to produce L and R, or the (L-R) is just ignored by a mono receiver.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I tried a circuit with a differential amplifier some time ago but i ended up with mainly a white noise. I must have had it wrong. I'll give it an other try tomorrow.

Comment: In theory, yes, but in practice any difference in level or phase will cause "leakage" if uncompensated.  And audio tends to be perceived logarithmically so even a small percentage of imperfection can be substantial.

Comment: *I tried a circuit with a differential amplifier some time ago* And that's exactly the type of information **you should have included in the question** as that shows you did try something and also what skills you already have. Even if it didn't work, include the circuit, maybe only a small thing needed to be changed.

Comment: How accurately must "B" be recovered?

Answer (score 4):

You've been given 3-amp and 2-amp solutions. Let me present the 1-amp solution, the differential amp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzFKYA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This assumes equal value resistors. It has a lower input impedance than a 3-amp circuit, but that's probably not an issue for you.

Comment: This is why they are called operational amplifiers (op-amp), because they are used to do mathematical operations.

Answer (score 2):

A pair of inverting amplifiers will do the job.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8JWFR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An inverting subtractor circuit. Note that power supply decoupling capacitors are not shown.*

- OA1 inverts the A signal to give -A on the output.
- OA2 inverts the sum of the two signals fed into it so the  output is -(-A + (A + B)) = -B.
- To allow trimming of levels to get maximum elimination of the A signal replace R5 with a 4k7 in series with a 10k pot and trim until the A signal is at a minimum.

Note that both A and B are inverted so their relative phase will be correct even though inverted from the original. For audio this should be satisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

> I have two audio signals, A and A+B on two different wires. I would
>   like to know if there is a solution to electronically retrieve the B
>   signal alone.

You have a computer so download a free wave editor and input the two audio signals to your PC and save them as a stereo wave file. Next open the wave editor (I use Wavelab but it isn't free) and then open the wave file and use the tools you normally get to manipulate audio.

The easiest tool is one that inverts the A channel. Next, play the stereo file (with A inverted) as a mono file and you'll get B coming over your speakers.

> Is there any IC or any kind of circuit that could allow me to do that
>   kind of substract ?

Well you don't need an IC other than the ones in your PC.

Comment: Yeah but i specifically asked for an electronic oriented answer because I won't embed a computer in my project. But thanks.

Comment: You did say “any kind of circuit” and although this immediately implies a circuit it doesn’t disclude a system that contains a circuit of some kind. I just wanted to give wider options. Think laterally I was told decades ago. @VincentPerez

Answer (score 1):

An instrumentation amplifier would do the job, use a gain of one and you'll be able to subtract B from A+B

If you put A+B on the positive terminal and A on the negative terminal you'll get A+B-A=B. Keep in mind that you need to make sure that the instrumentation amplifier doesn't distort your signal and that you keep the signals outside of the [common mode range](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwigufm4xoTgAhWp5oMKHcKYBR4QFjAAegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.analog.com%2Fmedia%2Fen%2Ftechnical-documentation%2Fapplication-notes%2Fan-1401.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0uIz3CFSydQDzGjN2vgjrO) of the amplifier.

[image]
Source: https://hackaday.com/2016/03/18/beyond-measure-instrumentation-amplifiers/